# how to make NSUserDefaults show in Setting on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, application-settings

according to this image, i try to save data in NSUserDefaults but my App not have application setting in menu Setting on iPhone?

how can i make this?
thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Application Preferences chapter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH13-SW10) of the iPhone Application Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) from Preferences and Settings Programming Guide